# .htaccess help needed, not sure if .htaccess is being processed at all :/

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

-------------Fixed (see bottom)------------

I have been working at this for a day now but with no luck.
I am trying to get a 4 char request (url-shortener) to forward to a particular page but I just can't get it to work.
This is what I have in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]{4})$ view.php?short=$1
```

Here is what I have in the vhost file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "bla bla/jewd.co/public_html"
        ErrorLog "bla bla bla"
        CustomLog "bla bla bla" common
        ServerName  jewd.lo
        ServerAlias jewd.lo
    <Directory "bla blajewd.co/public_html">
        Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried all sorts of variations but no luck. Obviously I do not have the word "bla" in any file I just wanted to shorten the lines.
Any help greatly appreciated as I'm quite a newbie when it comes to rewrite.

One more point, the local host is jewd.lo and it will be going live to jewd.co just to clear up any confusion :)
Thanks
Jonn

----------Edit-----------

I have since confirmed that mod-rewrite is indeed working and I have also tried with RewriteBase / but no luck.

----------- Fixed --------------

Ok, I am not sure which bit of tinkering has fixed the problem but somewhere along the way the page has changed from The

requested URL /1f8r was not found on this server.

to

The requested URL /view.php was not found on this server.

Day 1 week 1 I suppose, always create a page that you are forwarding to before you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]{4})$ view.php?short=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Oops, should have refreshed before posting :)